# In how many ways can we arrange 16 persons in 8 buildings and each building should have only 2 persons

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can we arrange $16$ persons in $8$ buildings so that each building has only $2$ people?
My answer is $16!/(2^8)$ but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why are you not sure?

Comment: I just have doubts:)))

Comment: You can place two people in each building in $\binom{16}{2}\binom{14}{2}\binom{12}{2}\binom{10}{2}\binom{8}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}$ ways, which simplifies to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct:

Firstly, put all $16$ people in line like this:

$$A_1A_2A_3A_4\cdots A_{16}$$

The line can also be:

- First person in building $1$
- Second person in building $1$
- First person in building $2$
- Second person in building $2$
- $\cdots$
- First person in building $9$
- Second person in building $8$

Of course there are $16!$ ways of putting them in line.

Now, sort them into eight groups:

$$A_1A_2|A_3A_4|A_5A_6|A_7A_8|A_9A_{10}|A_{11}A_{12}|A_{13}A_{14}|A_{15}A_{16}$$

We will take just one case: $A_1$ and $A_2$ in building $1$, $A_3$ and $A_4$ in building $2$,... $A_{15}$ and $A_{16}$ in the building $8$.

- $A_1$ and $A_2$ in building $1$: two ways to switch them in building $1$.
- $A_3$ and $A_4$ in building $2$: two ways to switch them in building $2$.

$\cdots$

- $A_{15}$ and $A_{16}$ in the building $8$: two ways to switch them in building $8$.

So there are $2^8$ ways to swap pairs of people around just their buildings for each case, but we only count once for each case, so the answer is $16!/2^8$.

Comment: Thank you man:))

Comment: You're welcome, you can click the green checkmark below the down arrow to accept this answer and get some points.